Mount SECURE smb share with cifs
I'm on Kubuntu 24.04.1 and I've managed to succesfully mount a smb share with cifs by adding it in /etc/fstab, with this line:
//192.168.10.122/Test /mnt/Test cifs user,noauto,user=test,password=test 0 0

The problem is that the password is in plain text which is not secure. So I've followed a new guide, by creating a credential file (.smb_cred) with chmod 600 (read and write) and put this line instead:
//192.168.10.122/Test /mnt/Test cifs uid=1000,credentials=/home/test/.smb_cred,iocharset=utf8 0 0

The problem is that it doesn't work. I see the mounted file but it's empty.

This has been designated a duplicate but if you read the question and the accepted answer you will note that is has nothing to do with the credentials file itself. It has to do with how fstab mounts can sometimes try to execute before the network stack is fully operational at boot. Hence the x-systemd.automount suggestion for example.

With that answer, this question makes even less sense. If OP thought the line with noauto was working, then they must have been mounting manually. So why wouldn't they try doing that with the second line? If they did, and it failed, they would have got some error. Voting to leave closed, because this is unclear to me.


I'm on Kubuntu 24.04.1 and I've managed to succesfully mount a smb
share with cifs by adding it in /etc/fstab, with this line:
//192.168.10.122/Test /mnt/Test cifs user,noauto,user=test,password=test 0 0


It's not automounting since you specified noauto in the declare statement. You have given a non-root user the ability to mount it however with the preceding user option.
//192.168.10.122/Test /mnt/Test cifs uid=1000,credentials=/home/test/.smb_cred,iocharset=utf8 0 0

That line is attempting to do the opposite. It's attempting to automatically mount the share at boot time.
After a reboot if the share doesn't mount open a terminal and run:
sudo mount -a

If the share is now mounted you can either:

Incorporate the user,noauto method you used in the first declaration:
//192.168.10.122/Test /mnt/Test cifs user,noauto,uid=1000,credentials=/home/test/.smb_cred 0 0


Or, use a systemd automounter: x-systemd.automount:
//192.168.10.122/Test /mnt/Test cifs uid=1000,credentials=/home/test/.smb_cred,iocharset=utf8,x-systemd.automount 0 0



Note: If you have an encrypted home directory the credentials file needs to be someplace else like /etc/samba/cred-files/.smb_cred
